# Small description on github defined from the terminal

Tags: github, terminal

Is it possible to define de small description of a project on github by using a command on my laptop's terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [edit repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#edit) endpoint in the GitHub API:

```
PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo
```

Include the required `name` parameter and the optional `description` in your request JSON. You will have to [authenticate](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) first.

Comment: I did not know at all the API of github. I will play with this. Thanks !